# Protobuf 2.6.0 response error on Mac: tar: Unrecognized archive format

Tags: macos, homebrew, protocol-buffers

I cannot install the Protobuf 2.6.0, detail as below:

```
ryous-MacBook-Pro:~ raniys$ protoc --version
libprotoc 2.6.0
ryous-MacBook-Pro:~ raniys$ cd /Users/raniys/Downloads/protobuf-2.6.0 
ryous-MacBook-Pro:protobuf-2.6.0 raniys$ ./autogen.sh 
Google Test not present.  Fetching gtest-1.5.0 from the web...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1586  100  1586    0     0   2948      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2953
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

The protobuf 2.6.1 cannot be find by brew:

```
ryous-MacBook-Pro:~ raniys$ brew install protobuf261
Error: No available formula with the name "protobuf261" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

macOS version: 10.12.1
Homebrew 1.0.8

Thanks for kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this, the below is a copy from the [link](https://github.com/google/protobuf/issues/2387):

> 1. run command 'brew install protobuf' to install the protobuf, the version of protobuf should be 3.1.0;
> 2. download the protobuf-2.6.1:
>      https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v2.6.1/protobuf- 
>      2.6.1.tar.bz2
> 3. Uncompress and cd to the protobuf-2.6.1 folder:

```
./autogen.sh

./configure

make

make install
```

> *4. download the protobuf-objc and build(only for oc):

```
git clone https://github.com/alexeyxo/protobuf-objc.git

cd protobuf-objc

./scripts/build.sh
```

> 5. Try command 'protoc --version' in the terminal, if the protobuf version is showing, means all finished, else please re-do the step 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

The 2.6.0 source tarball is just old and tries to fetch a link that no longer exists. I would recommend upgrading to a newer version such as 3.1 unless you have some particular reason to stick with 2.6.0.